# SharePoint Online - limit apps / lists available

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, modern-experience, list-template

My customer wants to limit the Apps (basically list templates, libraries, etc.) available in a site.

So after you create a team site or communication site, when the owner goes to add an app, how to limit what is available so they can't create a travel request or issue tracking list for example.

This would have to be the default behavior for all sites across the tenant - limit what apps/lists can be created. Any help in pointing me to the best approach to get this done would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable list templates by using PowerShell command:

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableModernListTemplateIds '<template ID>'
```

Where the template ID is:

- Issue tracker: 'C147E310-FFB3-0CDF-B9A3-F427EE0FF1CE'
- Travel requests: 'C51CF376-87CF-0E8F-97FF-546BC60FF1CE'

**Reference**:

[Control settings for lists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-lists)

Comment: This does not solve the issue at hand 100% -- for classic list templates (shown only when you click through "add an app" this would not work. this appears to work only for the new list template experience. Would you have a suggestion for example to prevent people from creating one of the classic lists such as 'Announcements' or 'Discussion Board' etc?